# Full Page image zoom overlay like in this article:

Tags: javascript, web, react

In this article images can be zoomed into full screen with a single click:

https://medium.design/image-zoom-on-medium-24d146fc0c20

The great thing is, it overlays the whole page instead of switching to a new page. Is there a library (preferably react compatible) package that does something like this?
Basically put the image into fullscreen with just a single click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A certain chatbot was a lot more helpful

react-image-lightbox
react-modal-image

Answer (score 1):

Somebody wrote a js library to mimic this :)

https://medium-zoom.francoischalifour.com/

License: MIT

How to use: https://github.com/francoischalifour/medium-zoom#usage

Comment: does this support video?